# Crystal reports blob field original size

Tags: image, crystal-reports, size, blob, default

I am inserting an image in the crystal report by dragging a field of type picture from the database fields. The image is inserted as a blob field with a default (original) size even though in the database the image can have different sizes. The problem is that the image does not preserve its original size. Is there a way how specify the original size of the image in crystal reports?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal report will not auto- re-size the image. So better to set the original size in Crystal report

Answer (score 0):

try this code in c#:

```
        CRAXDRT.Report report1 = new CRAXDRT.Report();
        CRAXDRT.Application app = new CRAXDRT.Application();
        report1 = app.OpenReport("YorReport.rpt", OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault);
        for (int i = 1; i < report1.Sections.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < report1.Sections[i].ReportObjects.Count + 1; j++)
            {
                try
                {
                    CRAXDRT.BlobFieldObject t1 = (CRAXDRT.BlobFieldObject)report1.Sections[i].ReportObjects[j];
                    if (t1.Name == "YourBlobFieldName")
                    {
                        t1.Height = 200;
                        t1.Width = 200;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Can Grow** checkbox for the BLOB field.
That will auto size the field by image's original size.